# Navigation controller is not navigating back (The activity displays 2 fragments at the same time)

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller, back

i'm trying to implement Navigation Component in my project, and i running with this issue, i have Fragment A and B. i successfully go from A to B but when i'm on B, i have no way to coming back to A like i usually do, like if NavController stopped working.

Also, Worth to mention that i replaced Toolbar with my own fragment T for in the future define custom behaviours, and also being able to be replaced dinamically.

MainActivity:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by viewBinding(ActivityMainBinding::inflate)
    private val viewmodel: MainViewmodel by viewModels()

    private val toolbarFragment: BaseToolbarFragment by lazy {
        BaseToolbarFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initializeToolbar()
    }

    /**
     * method called from Fragment A
     */
    fun configureToolbarForFragmentA() {
        viewmodel.setBaseToolbar(resources.getString(R.string.toolbar_fragment_a_title))
    }

    /**
     * method called from Fragment B
     */
    fun configureToolbarForFragmentB() {
        viewmodel.setBaseToolbar(resources.getString(R.string.toolbar_fragment_b_title), true)
    }

    /**
     * initialize toolbar container
     */
    private fun initializeToolbar() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            add(binding.toolbarContainer.id, toolbarFragment)
            commit()
        }
    }
}
```

FragmentA:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class FragmentA :
    Fragment(R.layout.fragment_a) {

    private val viewModel: ViewmodelA by activityViewModels()
    private val binding: FragmentABinding
            by viewBinding(FragmentABinding::bind)
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        binding.viewmodel = viewModel

        setUpViews()
        setUpToolbar()
        observeData()
    }

    private fun setUpViews() {
        setUpForwardButton()
        setUpRadioButtons()
        setUpTextInputs()
    }

    private fun setUpForwardButton() {
        binding.forwardButton.setOnClickListener {
            ...
            // Formulary validations
            ...
            if (isValidated) {
                viewModel.fragmentACompleted()
            }
        }

    ...
    // Another Views Logic Set up
    ...

    // Call the MainActivity method to configure toolbar for this fragment
    private fun setUpToolbar() {
        if (activity is MainActivity) {
            (activity as MainActivity).configureToolbarForFragmentA()
        }
    }

    /**
     * [ViewmodelA.problem] LiveData is updated and the value is instance of [FormAModel]
     * then go to [FragmentB]
     */
    private fun observeData() {
        viewModel.problem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if (it is FormAModel) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_from_fragment_a_to_fragment_b)
            }
        }
    }
```

FragmentB:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class FragmentB : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_b) {

    private val binding : FragmentBBinding
        by viewBinding(FragmentBBinding::bind)

    // FragmentB and FragmentA shares the same viewmodel
    private val viewmodel : ViewmodelA by activityViewModels()

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

        setUpToolbar()

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback {

            // The following Commented code is what i tried (separatedly) and do nothing
            //navController.popBackStack()
            //navController.navigateUp()
            //navController.navigate(R.id.go_back_to_createLinearProgramProblemFragment)
            //navController.popBackStack(R.id.createLinearProgramProblemFragment, false)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call [MainActivity.configureToolbarForDefineLinearProgramProblemCreation] 
     * to configure Toolbar for this fragment
     */
    private fun setUpToolbar() {
        if (activity is MainActivity) {
            (activity as MainActivity).configureToolbarForFragmentB()
        }
    }
}
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.linearprogramming.framework.view.fragment.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b">
        <!--

        <action
            android:id="@+id/go_back_to_fragmentA"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentA"/>

        -->
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.linearprogramming.framework.view.fragment.FragmentA"
        android:label="FragmentA"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_from_fragment_a_to_fragment_b"
            app:destination="@id/fragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

If needed i provide Toolbars code, right now it's just a fragment that has as viewmodel the Mainviemodel from MainActivity in order to observe a ToolbarModel changes in order to know what ToolbarFragment and their configs. (for example)

My ToolbarFragment updated it's config on FragmentB sucessfully to add an ImageButton for the classical BackButton.

```
binding.backButton.setOnClickListener {
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
}
```

And it successfuly invokes the callBack from FragmentB

```
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Back from Define Problem fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // All the commented code below isn't working at all
            //navController.popBackStack()
            //navController.navigateUp()
            //navController.navigate(R.id.go_back_to_createLinearProgramProblemFragment)
            //navController.popBackStack(R.id.createLinearProgramProblemFragment, false)
        }
```

As stated via a comment directly in the code, none of those method are working as intended like i've read through another similar posts on StackOverflow.

EDIT:

i forgot to add main activity .xml and (as it is) the current toolbarFragment (in the future i'm planning to add new toolbars with different functionalities). I don't have DEEP knowledge about fragments but has something to be related to showing 2 fragments in the same activity and using navigations that breaks the whole BackPress behaviour.

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".framework.view.activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:name="com.example.linearprogramming.framework.view.fragment.BaseToolbarFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_base_toolbar" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_container"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_linear_program_problem" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

BaseToolbarFragment:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class BaseToolbarFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_base_toolbar) {

    private val binding: FragmentBaseToolbarBinding by viewBinding(FragmentBaseToolbarBinding::bind)
    private val viewmodel: MainViewmodel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        observeData()
        setUpViews()
    }

    private fun observeData() {
        viewmodel.toolbar.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if (it is ToolbarModel.BaseToolbar) {
                binding.title.text = it.title.value
                binding.backButton.visibility =
                    if (it.hasBackButton.value == true) View.VISIBLE
                    else View.GONE
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpViews() {
        binding.backButton.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

ViewmodelA:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@HiltViewModel
class ViewmodelA @Inject constructor(

) : ViewModel() {
    
    ...
    // Observable LiveData
    ...

    private val __problemModel = MutableLiveData<Problem>()
    val problemModel: LiveData<Problem> 


    // This updates problemModel to be observed in the fragments 
    // (A, B, C, D, ...) 
    fun fragmentACompleted() {
        _problemModel.value = FragmentAProblem(
           // values obtained from FragmentA Questionnaire
        )
    }

    // TODO the problemModel generated from FragmentB is the 
    // continuation of FragmentA Questionnaire
    fun fragmentBCompleted() {
       _problemModel.value = FragmentBProblem(
          // values obtained from fragmentB Questionnaire
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `OnBackPressHandler` for anything, just remove it. When you are in fragment B, press back button then NavController will automatically pop it back stack and you will see fragment A.

Comment: That was the first thing to fail, the whole BackButton (even the physical button) stops working when i display FragmentB, press BackButton does nothing, even pressing it like desesperately 10 times won't close the app

Comment: You can't go back because of this `viewModel.problem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner)`. You will always get the old value that send you back to fragmentB. DO NOT use live-data for event, try to use `SharedFlow`

Comment: Could you believe that i happen to discover THAT was the issue ? i came here just to share that same response (except for the part of SharedFlow) and marke it as ressolved. 

Thanks for your efforts to also find the answer!

Comment: fshdn19 second answer is the solution